# Looking for a Sci-fi comedy movie, where enemy steals mojo

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for the name of the movie where the enemy stole (don't remember exactly) mojo from other persons. It was a sci-fi action comedy movie.

I have this one clip, the enemy is the one with the bald head.

[image: Gif of 6 characters laughing maniacally, they are the bad guys led by the one in the middle ina clean grey suit and a bald head, a man with an eye patch stands to his side with a woman in a shiny suit to his left]

Comment: Are you serious? Google image search gives me over 25 billion hits, with the summaries on the first page answering your question five times. Coincidentally 25 BILLION (spoken loudly) is only a quarter of the ransom Dr Evil demanded. And it's about 90% comedy, 9.9% action, and 0.1% scifi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Austin Powers: The Spy Who Shagged Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145660/).  Dr. Evil (the bald guy in the animated gif) steals the "mojo" of Austin Powers.